# GCP Database migration service for Postgres - how to migrate a database with a name other than "postgres"?

Tags: database, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, database-migration, database-mirroring

I'm trying to do a database migration using `GCP Database Migration Service`

My source database is of `Postgres` type (hosted on `Heroku`), but the name of the database is not `postgres` but rather something like `d12bdsdjs` ...

My question is ... is there a way for me to use the `GCP Database Migration Service` to somehow migrate this database ? There seems to be no field on the form where I can provide this value in `GCP console` ... maybe I can somehow set it if I create my `migration job` using the `GCP SDK` or something ?

Please advise

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing your issue, it is confirmed that `Heroku` is not currently supported.

But it appears that it is planned: The idea is to push apps from Heroku to GCP while also switching the database over to Cloud SQL PostgreSQL.

In conclusion, unfortunately, `Database Migration Service` does not support Heroku PostgreSQL at the moment.

Comment: And what if I wanted to copy data from somewhere other than Heroku ? Like from an on-prem database instance, where I have two databases for example like "postgres" and "dev" ... is it somehow possible to copy only the database with the name "dev" ? It seems that GCP Migration Service tries to copy "postgres" database by default ... and there is no way to make it copy a database with a different name.

Answer (score 1):

> Like from an on-prem database instance, where I have two databases for example like "postgres" and "dev" ... is it somehow possible to copy only the database with the name "dev" ? It seems that GCP Migration Service tries to copy "postgres"

Here are some alternative methods for migration [1](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/migrating-postgresql-to-gcp), [2](https://medium.com/mavenlink-product-development/migrating-postgres-to-google-cloud-sql-2637b1caab4d). These do not need Database Migration Service to Migrate an on-premise database to Cloud SQL. As your problem seems you already have a database named `postgres`.